Swiper JS Custom CSS Problem for Multiple Slider
Actually I want to add several sliders on my homepage but unfortunately the css folders are working together for each and every slider even if I keep them in seperate folders.
These are the two css folders I created
The Following are the codes inside both of my css folders
this is css file 1
this is css file 2
Both of the folders state different widths but in real the sliders receive the css of the same file and I cannot use a specific css file for one specific slider. PLease let me know what may I do to use the css properties seperately?
I try to style both the sliders in different ways but cannot do that due to facing issues because of integrating several sliders in one page

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
